# Typo in Equation 7.122 in Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, svm

In Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning the author calls Equation 7.122 in Ch 7.2.3 the log likelihood when it is actually the likelihood. I couldn't find this listed in any errata online. I've outlined why below but beware it is kind of long and blatantly obvious so I guess I'm more seeking to document this than asking for clarification as I couldn't find this in any errata or on Google.

You have a $K$ class classification problem with targets $t_{nk} \in \{0,1\}$ with a $1$-of-$K$ encoding scheme (only one of the $K$ targets $t_{nk}$ is one and the rest are zero for given $n$) where the class probabilities are given by $y_k(x)=Softmax(w_k^T x)$.

The probability of class $k$ for training data point $x_n$ is given by $y_{nk}=y_k(x_n)$ i.e we have;

$$p(t_{nk}|x_n)=y_{nk}=y_k(x_n)$$

Define a vector of all the target values, $t_{nk}$, for observation $x_n$;

$$\textbf{t}_n=\begin{bmatrix}
t_{n1} & t_{n2} & ... & t_{nK}\\
\end{bmatrix}^T$$

then
$$p(\textbf{t}_n|x_n)=\prod_{k=1}^K y_{nk}^{t_{nk}}$$

since the $t_{nk}$ have a $1$-of-$K$ encoding.

Then $T$ is a matrix whose $n^{th}$ row is $\textbf{t}_n^T$.

i.e. the $(n,k)^{th}$ element of $T$ is $T_{nk}=t_{nk}$.

Note I omitted the dependence on the weight vectors previously.

Then the likelihood is given by;

$$p(T|w_1,...,w_K)=\prod_{n=1}^N p(\textbf{t}_n|x_n)=\prod_{n=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^K y_{nk}^{t_{nk}}$$

which is the same as 7.122 and is the likelihood not the log likelihood.

Comment: Why not open an issue [here](https://github.com/yousuketakada/prml_errata/issues) instead?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.